# Problem building simple app in both Visual Studio Code and 202

Tags: c++

The following code complies fine in both VS2022 and VSCODE.

```
#import <iostream>

int main()
{

  std::cout << "test" << std::endl'

 return 0;

}
```

The problem is, when I hit build, it says it cannot find the exe specified.

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU1r7.jpg)

Please ignore the typo in the image, I've fixed that, but the error remains.

Comment: The editor in your IDE shows your file was not saved. Although with that said I suspect your antivirus is the problem if the code compiled fine as you say.

Comment: Please can you put the error message from the image into the question so that other people can search for it - also imgur.com is blocked by some people's internet settings.